# Decimal to binary Free Pascal

Tags: pascal

I need a code to go from decimal to binary numbers, but my program shows them invert, example: needs to show 1011000 but it brings out 0001101.
+ I cant use massives and array in this program.

```
  var
    x,y,i:longint;

  BEGIN
    readln(y);

    repeat
      x:= y mod 2;
      y:= y div 2;
      write(x);
    until y = 0;
  END.
```

Comment: Also cant use String!

Comment: That rules out the simple solution: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/strutils/inttobin.html

Comment: Can you use Pascal bit operations? And what's a "massive"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use recursion function. For example:

```
procedure dec2bin(y) 
BEGIN
  x := y mod 2;
  y := y mod 2;
  if y > 1 then
    dec2bin(y)
  end
  write(x)
END
BEGIN
readln(y);
dec2bin(y)
END.
```

I'm not sure in correct syntax because I working with Pascal long time ago. But I think you can understand my idea and make this.

Answer (score 1):

This should answer what you are looking for

```
function decimalToBinary(a:LongInt):String;
var d:Integer;
str:String;
Begin
  str:='';
  while a>0 do begin
    d:=a mod 2;
    str:=concat(IntToStr(d),str);
    a:=a div 2;
  end;
  decimalToBinary:=str;
End;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code. It works!

```pascal
program convert;
var 
    number : integer;

procedure dec2bin(x : integer);
begin
    // general case
    if (x > 1) then dec2bin(x div 2);

    // to print the result
    if (x mod 2 = 0) then write('0')
    else write('1');
end;

begin
    write('Decimal: '); readln(number);
    write('Binary : ');
    dec2bin(number);
end.
```